# the CNN model well trained but can't predict real data

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, regression

I'm developing a CNN regression model for gait. It seems the model is well trained, with low val_loss and low loss. however, the model does not work well to predict real data. In this training process, the data used is gait data generated from the force plate and plantar pressure. the force plate consists of 6 values and the plantar pressure consists of 89 values. then the experimental scenario used in making this model is data collection simultaneously, so the plantar pressure will be placed above the force plate and someone will walk on the plantar pressure and force plate simultaneously. the data generated from both is 50 data in 1 second. The duration of the experiment that I did was 5 minutes so my total training data was 15000. the main thing, I'm making a regression model to predict force plates using plantar pressure. as I said above the model is well trained, but the model cannot work properly for real data during testing. The following is the result of process training and testing using real data.

the data samples:

> Force Plate Data: [ 4.46733, 4.39629, -34.2351 , -4077.23 , -6206.81 ,
> -874.539 ]
>
> Force Plate Data Shape : (15000,6)
>
> SmartInsole Data: [ 0. 0. 0. 13. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 15. 92. 60. 0. 36.
> 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 62. 80. 58. 37. 0. 0. 0. 0. 40. 83. 72. 32. 22. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 98. 108. 74. 56. 30. 17. 0. 0. 44. 121. 127. 83. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 83. 64. 63. 63. 77. 70. 43. 55. 115. 138. 144. 137. 0. 0. 0. 0. 66. 107. 127. 146. 150. 52. 0. 0. 0. 129. 133. 18. 0. 0. 0.]
>
> SmartInsole Data Shape : (15000,89)

the training process:

[image: Training Process]
[image: Model Loss]

training prediction results:
[image: FX_Training_Predictions]
[image: MX_Trainig Predictions]

the prediction results when I testing using real data:
[image: FX_Testing_Predictions]
[image: MX_Testing_Predictions]

I'm confused why this can happen, even though the training results are quite good and the resulting val_loss and loss results are also very small. then because of this problem I found a solution by adding the number of sequences to the plantar pressuser data. because plantar pressure is able to generate 50 data in 1 second, so here I will add a number of sequences 1–50 at the first index for each plantar pressure data. so the plantar pressure data which originally consisted of 89 values, now will be 90 values because I added 1 data (data number of sequence). Below is an illustration of adding the number of sequences to plantar pressure data.
[image]

The training process from adding the number of sequences in the plantar pressure data will be very helpful in the training and testing using real data.

the training process with adding number of sequnces:
[image: Training Process with number of sequnces]
[image: Model Loss with number of sequnces]

Training predictions with adding number of sequnces:
[image: FX_Training_With_Adding_Number_Sequnces]
[image: MX_Training_With_Adding_Number_Sequnces]

the predictions using real data with adding number of sequnces:
[image: FX_Testing_With_Adding_Number_Sequnces]
[image: MX_Testing_With_Adding_Number_Sequnces]

this is very weird to me, why when I don't add the number of sequences to the plantar pressure data the results of training results will be good but when I test the model using real data, the model is unable to predict real data. however, if I add a number of sequences to the plantar pressure data, the training results will be better than without adding a number of sequences and during testing, the model is able to predict real data quite well. I've read a lot of papers and looking for information on things like this but I can't find it. I hope someone here can provide a logical reason why all this could happen.

below is the link of my full code of my project : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nWvbTAGgvnUGwVyQ6nZEX1xxOH--mucZ?usp=sharing

Comment: I most likely did not get the details of your project from your description - however sequential models are prone to an effect called cold-start, in which the model performs poorly on the initial inputs, until it got ramped-up. During training and validation this effect usually goes undetected.

Answer (score 0):

Your signal is experiencing sharp spikes (can be modeled with a delta function) and then non-smooth variation. This makes it hard for the RNN model to follow.

Try singal decomposition using something like wavelets
Predict each frequency band seperated and then apply the inverse transform the predicted signals

Comment: can you give me reference?

Comment: This seems to be a nice explanation https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2021/9942410/ and also there are othe ones here  https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=wavelet+lstm&btnG=

Comment: I've try to train a model using decomposing data using wavelets decomposition. but the result it same.will good on training but the model can't predict the real data

Comment: you can see this code https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11rB6bwyKUEwKphUTwEZ2WILPx4AbC_M7?usp=sharing

Comment: I wasnt thinking about using wavelet for denoising. I was thinking about training a network for every channel and then creating a new signal from predictions on each channel . there would be less spikes in decomposed channels

Comment: because based on your reference above they doing decomposition with wavelet also. then they will train model using LSTM

Comment: so can you help me how to train it using wavelet neural network?

Comment: can you try this? https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-wavelets/

Comment: how to make my input data usable in wnn, because look like different

Comment: I am guessing : from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(DWT.DWT(name="haar",concat=0))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(nb_classes, activation="softmax"))
model.summary()  using this code, you dont need to change your input shape

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).